# Server refreshes page after webservice saves file

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a webservice build with WebApi that gets a file from the database, saves it to a temporary folder with a unique identifier and returns a link to that file.

However when the service saves the file to the temporary folder, the page where I call this webservice from javascript refreshes. The webservice and the webpage are hosted on the same site.

this is the code that creates the image

```
...
var bm = Image.FromStream(ms);
bm = RezizeImage(bm, 1000, 1000);
bm.Save(path + tempname,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
...
```

If I comment out the `bm.Save` line the service does not refresh the page.
The call from javascript is just a basic `axios.get` and the webapi is `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.5.2.6`

Calling the webservice from Postman also triggers a reload of the page.

Anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it?

let me know if you need more information.

Comment: maybe because you forget to do `e.preventDefault();` in your js?

Comment: I have done tests with a webservice that just returns a url to an existing image (no saving) and it works as expected. The refresh only happens when the webservice does the file save operation.

Comment: then my last guess will be that you are on development machine and your JS is running on WebPack with live reloading or something simular. So, when you save some files that live reloading mechanism observes - your page is reloading. Can you try to replace that file (`path + tempname`) by hands?

Comment: I'm developing a MVC site in VisualStudio, the reloading goes trough BrowserLink and it's not automated as far as I know.

Comment: BrowserLink should reload page when one of your resources is updated. Can you try to replace that file (`path + tempname`) by hands?

Comment: If I replace the file, the page gets refreshed. Turning off BrowserLink actually fixed the problem. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help. I have to say, this behavior is a bit confusing, as normally I have to press the key-command to refresh the page trough BrowserLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BrowserLink is monitoring your source files for change and reloads entire page when some of this files are changed (by you or by someone else). So, if you WebAPI overwrite (by calling `bm.Save(path + tempname,ImageFormat.Jpeg);`) some file that you BrowserLink observes - your page will be reloaded.

To test it - replace this file "by hands" or just disable BrowserLink.